# GCloud https to external ID and Cloud DNS not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, https, reverse-dns

as will be obvious, I do not know much about networking and do appreciate all hints and explanations. 
I wrote a little website application in flask using gunicorn and nginx. It is containerised, and works locally. My goal is to deploy it on gcloud and have a proper domain name pointing at it.

I set up a small compute instance. I used the standard http and https firewalls on that instance. I have an external IP EXT_IP reserved and set up. Additionally, I set up allow-firewalls for 443 ingress and egress on that instance. I run the docker container while mapping the ports 80 and 443 to the container port. I am not sure whether it is necessary to map the 443 to the container port.
When I run http://[EXT_IP] the application works just as expected.
When I however just click on the external IP or use an https request, I do get a "Secure Connection Failed" error.

When I run `nmap EXT_IP` I get the following output, which looks sensible.

```
Host is up (0.039s latency).
Not shown: 994 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
80/tcp   open   http
443/tcp  open   https
3389/tcp closed ms-wbt-server
8000/tcp closed http-alt
8001/tcp closed vcom-tunnel

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 10.64 seconds
```

Additionally I tried to set up Cloud DNS. I purchased a domain on Google domains and set up an A record for the domain to the reserved external IP and a CNAME alias for the www.domain to the domain.
When I attempt to go to the site using the domain, I get a not found error.
When I use `host domain_name` I get

```
Host [Domain Name] not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

I suspect that two things are going wrong. The https and the DNS mapping seem to be separate issues, but I am not sure.

Could anyone help me how to resolve either or both of those? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: **1**. Have you installed SSL certificate and configured web server to use HTTPS protocol? If not there's no surprise that your service doesn't work via HTTPS **2**. Actually  you can [configure DNS records](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3290350?hl=en) at Google Domain instead of using Cloud DNS. **3**. (If you need it) Have a look at the documentation [Create a managed public zone](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/quickstart#create_a_managed_public_zone). Have you configured DNS servers for your domain same to NS records in your zone? Please share your domain name if possible.

Comment: **4**. Yes, HTTPS and DNS are separate issues. **5**. Meanwhile, you successfully configured GCP Firewall.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look into it SSL certificates, as I have done nothing with them. The web server here is nginx, right? Do you have by any chance a good resource handy for a layman? The domain name is dataforconsultants.uk . Thanks again!

Comment: Let's finish with DNS first. Have you solved it?

Comment: Sorry, hadn't had time yet. Actually, how would I see that I am finished?

Comment: So I followed the link you gave for section 2. There it directs me to the Custom Resource Records creation. What do I put in for the ipv4 address (I am not sure what that is)? I put the external Ip in and it said within 48 hours it should work. is that the correct way to proceed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213802/discussion-between-ajk-and-serhii-rohoza).

Comment: Yes, it's the correct way, and yes, you should use external IP. Have you [reserved external IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address)?  You can check DNS propagation with tools like https://dnsmap.io/ (it could be accessible in 24 hours or even earlier). After that, you'll be able to see your application via `http://domain.name` and/or `http://www.domain.name` if you configured DNS records correctly.

Comment: Meanwhile, have a look at the articles [How To Secure a Containerized Node.js Application with Nginx, Let's Encrypt, and Docker Compose](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-a-containerized-node-js-application-with-nginx-let-s-encrypt-and-docker-compose) and  [Nginx and Let’s Encrypt with Docker in Less Than 5 Minutes](https://medium.com/@pentacent/nginx-and-lets-encrypt-with-docker-in-less-than-5-minutes-b4b8a60d3a71) to solve issue with SSL.

Comment: Thank you for confirmation! Please accept/upvote my answer if my comments were useful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have two separate issues**:

- DNS server configuration;
- NGINX web server configuration.

**To solve issue with DNS** you should follow one from two ways :

1. use [Google Domains](https://domains.google/) only:

   - configure necessary DNS records at Google Domains side by following documentation [Resource records](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3290350?hl=en);
   - [remove](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/quickstart#clean-up) your zone from Google Cloud DNS.
2. switch to [Google Cloud DNS](https://cloud.google.com/dns):

   - [create](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/quickstart) managed zone for your domain;
   - [set custom DNS servers](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3290309?hl=en) (same as NS records you can see at the previous step in created managed zone) for your domain.

After that you should wait for 24-48 hours for DNS propagation. You can check status of DNS online with services like [dnsmap.io](https://dnsmap.io/) or [mxtoolbox.com](https://mxtoolbox.com/dnspropagation.aspx). If everything was configured correctly, you'll be able to see your application via `http://domain.name` and/or `http://www.domain.name`.

**To solve issue with SSL** you should follow instructions from these articles  [How To Secure a Containerized Node.js Application with Nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-a-containerized-node-js-application-with-nginx-let-s-encrypt-and-docker-compose), Let's Encrypt, and Docker Compose and [Nginx and Let’s Encrypt with Docker in Less Than 5 Minutes to solve issue with SSL](https://medium.com/@pentacent/nginx-and-lets-encrypt-with-docker-in-less-than-5-minutes-b4b8a60d3a71).